# Angular4 micro front-ends

Tags: angular, webpack

We have an application composed by multiple services, where there is a edge service routing and load balancing all request to the individual services.

The backend REST API is deployed without problem on each server, but we have one single Angular4 application that references routes to modules that are developed in conjunction with this backend REST APIs.

If we release a new version of a service, we deploy the backend and the edge server starts to route to the new version.

The problem is that, we always need to redeploy the edge server in order to replace the full Angular4 application, because the specific module were updated.

We user angular-cli and it generates (and hashes) webpack bundles automatically. All our service modules are declared as npm dependencies in the main application and bundled as one.

How can we build, package and deploy the Angular4 application and our service modules, in order to make the main application reference external bundles and keep the routing working as expected?

Thanks in advance.

PS: the backend services and edge server are Spring Cloud applications using Netflix OSS.

Comment: are you worried about the hashes and donot want them ?

Comment: It's not the hash my concern (this is something I want in order to control caching), my concern is: I understood Angular needs to load modules on bootstrap. How can I do that if modules are defined in separated servers?

Comment: Making multiple angular 4 apps would create problems with routes, instead you should try lazy loading the different modules, if the bundle size is your concern.

Comment: My concern is: I want to release and deploy parts of the application separately. If I do a change on a component responsible for a specific route, I don't want to rebuild the whole Angular application and deploy all-in-one. In this case, lazy loading seems to be a solution. But how can we do that with angular-cli? Seems that you can with SystemJS, but the angular generated build uses Webpack. But I may be wrong,

Comment: Hi @RicardoPiccoli, your problem is very interesting. Is there any progress on it?

Comment: Hi @Brozorec, our frontend developers gave up. They could made it work with SystrmJS but spent all effort in doing so. No time to attempt a definitive build using WebPack. We ended up with some NPM reusable modules and monolith Angular application.

Answer (score 1):

Angular-CLI 1.6 will code split your lazy-loaded feature modules into separate chunks that could, in theory, be deployed independently. `ng build`. Note that this only works if you are lazy-loading the feature modules.

The alternate solution would be a micro front-end architecture. Although the idea is in it infancy it is still worth exploring:

https://medium.com/@tomsoderlund/micro-frontends-a-microservice-approach-to-front-end-web-development-f325ebdadc16

https://micro-frontends.org/

Comment: That was my impression. I wanted to use micro-front end, but wasn't quite ready yet. Thanks.